# "Must declare the scalar variable" when trying to run UPDATE statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, table-variable

Trying to update two tables (`City` and `Location`) using two table variables (`@NameZip`, `@NameZip2`). The city names have `ZipCodes` and `ZipCodes` have `Names` instead of vice versa. Updates are changing City names and ZipCodes where they were wrongly entered. But getting the error:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@NameZip2".
>
> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@NameZip".

The query I wrote:

```
--first table variable
DECLARE @NameZip TABLE 
                 (
                     Zip_Code NVARCHAR(100),
                     Name NVARCHAR(100),
                     id_city INT
                 )

--second table variable
DECLARE @NameZip2 TABLE
                  (
                      Zip_Code nvarchar(100),
                      Name NVARCHAR(100),
                      id_city INT
                  )

--inserting into first table variable from City and Location table
INSERT INTO @NameZip (Zip_code, Name, id_city)
    SELECT B.Zip_Code, A.Name, A.id_city
    FROM City A 
    INNER JOIN Location B ON A.id_city = B.id_city 
                          AND Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

--inserting into second table variable from first table variable
INSERT INTO @NameZip2(Zip_code, Name, id_city)
    SELECT Name, Zip_Code, id_city
    FROM @NameZip

UPDATE City 
SET Name = (SELECT Name FROM @NameZip2)
WHERE City.id_city = @NameZip2.id_city -- I get error on this line

UPDATE Location
SET Zip_Code = (SELECT Zip_Code FROM @NameZip2)
WHERE Zip_Code = @NameZip.Zip_Code -- I get error on this line
```

Any inputs regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this with a join... but your table variables aren't really needed.

```
update c
set c.Name = n.Name
from City c
inner join @NameZip2 n on n.id_city = c.id_city

update L
set L.Zip_Code = n.Zip_Code
from Location L
inner join
@NameZip2 n on n.Zip_Code = L.Zip_Code
```

Can be written as...

```
update c
set c.Name = n.Name, c.Zip_Code = n.Zip_Code
from City c
inner join    
    (SELECT B.Zip_Code, A.Name, A.id_city
    FROM City A 
    INNER JOIN Location B ON A.id_city = B.id_city 
                          AND Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%') n
```

Comment: I get your point sir. Sorry for marking my answer as the right one. I'm accepting this answer because, it shows the other efficient way of reaching at the solution. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: No need to cal me sir or apologize good mate. I was just confused @schikkamksu

Answer (score 3):

use `update from join` syntax

```
update c
set Name = z.Name 
from City C
inner join @NameZip2 z on c.id_city =z.id_city
```

do the same for `location` table update as well.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers can help you change your code, I think it's interesting to explain  what's wrong with the code:

```
SET Name = (SELECT Name FROM @NameZip2)
```

This line can give you an error. If you're using `=` operator you must ensure the expression will return only one value. Even you being right that @NameZip2 has only one record, this is not a good approach, you could do this:

```
SET Name = (SELECT Top 1 Name FROM @NameZip2)
```

And this line:

```
WHERE Zip_Code = @NameZip.Zip_Code
```

Will not work because @NameZip is a table, and you should use a `SELECT` command instead of a `=`, this way:

```
WHERE Zip_Code = (SELECT TOP 1 Zip_Code FROM @NameZip)
```

Comment: Just to continue with Ricardo's thought, the dot notation in your original code makes me think you're trying to treat the table variable as though it were an array. That's not irrational, but SQL Server doesn't let you do that. :)